# Minimum number of observations to determine long range dependency

Tags: r, long-range-dependence

What is the minimum number of observations to be considered in order to determine long range dependency?

I'm trying to estimate Hurst parameter using R/S method. I've used [SELFIS](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~tkarag/Selfis/Selfis.html) as well as R.

Logically, since we are interested in *long range* dependency, we should have *enough* observations. [SELFIS](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~tkarag/Selfis/Selfis.html) requires at least 64 values before it could analyze. So, is that a standard value (or is there any standard value)?

Also, for the `rsFit` method of `fArma` package in R, does the `levels` parameter indicate that minimum value?

Comment: As you yourself point out, we need _enough_ observations. Naturally, what is _enough_ depends on how long the long range is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found these articles to be helpful in this context:

- "Estimators for long-range dependence: an empirical study" by Murad S. Taqqu, Vadim Teverovsky, Walter Willinger. Fractals, Vol. 3 (1995), pp. 785-798.
- "Estimators for Long Range Dependence: An Empirical Study" by William Rea, Les Oxley, Marco Reale, Jennifer Brown. Electronic J Stat. arXiv:0901.0762v1
- "What is the Required Series Length for Correct Self-similarity Analysis?" by Julio C. Ramírez Pacheco and Deni Torres Román

To summarize:

```
Method          Min # of observations

Whittle         ~ 2^8
Wavelet         ~ 2^13
Periodogram     ~ 2^15
R/S             None
```